# How to sync content (images and files) between plonesites

Tags: image, file, plone, synchronization

I have a client who has both a public website and an intranet. The client wants to have a shared media library between the two websites.

In the past this could be done with [Products.Zsyncer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.ZSyncer) or collective.PloneMultiSync2, but both these products are old and don't seem te be actively maintained.

What is the currently advisable way to solve this?

Comment: Is this master-master (both sides want write access to the shared parts) or would master-minion (one side read-only) suffice?

Comment: Either would be okay. Master-master would be nicer.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not exactly what you need, but a partial solution can be the usage of [Reflecto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.Reflecto).

Files and images should be loaded on the server filesystem (and so: they can be rsynced even if Plone sites are on different server) and to do this you must rely on additional stuff like an FTP or similar.

Comment: That is the solution I'm thinking of right now, or just building two browser views to handle the syncing.

Comment: Reflecto only works in 'show live' mode, at least then it shows the folder contents. The files are not usable from tinymce. With show live off, it doesn't show any content or reindex anything. Have you run into this?

Answer (score -1):

**Copying and bootstrapping a Plone site to a new computer**

1) Create a new site in the destination using Plone installer and make sure you can log-in to the site with temporary admin account

2) Copy var/filestorage/Data.fs from the old system to the new system - note that admin password is stored in Data.fs and the password given during the creation of a new site is no longer effective after Data.fs copy

3) Copy blobs from the old system to the new system by copying var/blobstorage/ folder

4) Copy src/ folder from the old system if you have any custom development code there

5) Copy buildout.cfg and other .cfg files

6) Rerun buildout in order to automatically re-download and configure all

7) Python packages needed to run the site
python bootstrap.py to make the buildout use new local Python interpreter
 8) Then bin/buildout to regenerate parts/ folder

**Copying site data in UNIX environment**

Below are example UNIX commands to copy a Plone site data from a computer to another over SCP/SSH connection. The actual username and folder locations depend on your system configuration.

**Note:** a copy of the Plone site configuration must already exist on the target computer. These instructions are only for copying / back-uping site data.

This operation can be perfomed on a running system - Data.fs is append only file and you will simply lose transactions which happened during the copying of the end of the file.

**Copy local to remote**

Run this command in your buildout Plone installation.

Copy Data.fs database:

```
scp -C -o CompressionLevel=9 var/filestorage/Data.fs plone@server.com:/srv/plone/site/var/filestorage
```

**Copy BLOB files using rsync**
BLOB files contain file and image data uploaded to your site. Since the actual content of file rarely changes after upload, rsync can synchronize only changed files using -a (archive) flag.

```
rsync -av --compress-level=9 var/blobstorage plone@server.com:/srv/plone/site/var
```

Comment: I already have both plone sites, which are completely different sites, so syncing the Data.fs would not work. I need to partially share content (defined by for instance a Collection or a Folder).